# how to extract from stored HTML using Python Newspaper

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-newspaper

I have crawled and stored the page HTML on my local drive. I now need to extract information like content, title, image etc... using Python Newspaper (Ver 0.1.2) and Python (Ver 2.7.10). I'm unable to find anything related to this on the Internet. How do I achieve the above?

Comment: Have you tried reading http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Im not familiar with this module, but it may have some useful information

Comment: @PeterSteele : Yes I did, but nothing related to extraction from saved HTML content in the documentation,

Comment: Did my answer help you? Also please take a look at this [overview usage document on newspaper](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview) that I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You likely solved this issue already. But here is a method to parse stored HTML files with *Newspaper*.

```
from newspaper import Article

article = Article('')
article.set_html(open("cnn_article.html").read())
article.parse()
title = article.title
authors = article.authors
text = article.text
keywords = article.meta_keywords
published_date = sorted({value for (key, value) in 
article.meta_data.items() if key == 'pubdate'})
```